# .htaccess folder as parameter to root index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I need is any subfolder to be passed as a parameter to the root index.php
This is the code and it actually works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(/[^/]*|)$ index.php?dir=$1/ [L,QSA]
```

There is a problem:

When the url is like this (no end slash after 'projects'):
`http://example.com/projects`

the rewrite rule changes the link in the address bar and it looks like this:
`http://example.com/projects/?dir=projects/`

Is there a chance the url in the address bar always stays the same(no matter if there is an end slash or not) so the dir parameter is not visible to the user?

I tried with multiple rules - the first one to add an end slash, and then the second rule to pass the directory as parameter, but with no luck so far.

EDIT: so far thanks to w3d I managed to get it working. In the .htaccess just add: 
DirectorySlash Off

Comment: Are you suggesting that when you do specify an end slash then the URL does not change in the address bar?

Comment: Exactly - which is just what I want

Comment: Well, my initial thought is that this is the result of `DirectorySlash On` (default) in mo_dir. Apache automatically appends (fixes) a slash to URLs that are a directory. However, I don't immediately see how your `RewriteRule` would produce the given result (where did `index.php` go)? Do you have any other directives? And why this would result in an external redirect, as opposed to an internal rewrite - as stated by your `RewriteRule` directive?

Comment: These are all the directives. I don't know how it omits the index.php and leaves just the query part. But I think that if with slash-at-the-end it works, there is a way it can work with no end slash. Is there logics if i try again with 2 rules - the first one to add a slash at the end, and the second one to pass the dir as parameter to the root?

Comment: Since `projects` is an actual directory on the file system, Apache automatically appends a slash onto the request (as mentioned above) - which could be the root cause of the problem. I'll try some tests myself shortly...

Comment: Thank you,  w3d! I tried with DirectorySlash Off and it seems to work now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Make the trailing slash mandatory in the `RewriteRule` pattern (and remove the `DirectorySlash Off` directive, ie. keep it `On`).

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?dir=$1/ [L,QSA]
```

---

As suggested in comments, this "strange" redirect is the result of mod_dir's `DirectorySlash On` directive, which is `On` by default. This can be quickly resolved by including `DirectorySlash Off` at the top of your .htaccess file (or making the trailing slash mandatory - see above and below).

The `DirectorySlash On` directive instructs Apache to automatically append a slash to URLs that end in a file system directory. In this sense it is "fixing" the URL. mod_dir achieves this with a 301 external redirect.

So, what is actually happening in the above, when `DirectorySlash` is enabled, is:

1. Initial request:
   `/projects` (no trailing slash)
2. Internal rewrite in .htaccess:
   `/index.php?dir=projects/` (note that the request URL is still `/projects`)
3. mod_dir now kicks in and "fixes" the initial request (`/projects` --> `/projects/`) by appending a slash to the end of the URL-path. However, the query string from the rewritten URL (above) is passed through:
   `/projects/?dir=projects/` (this is a 301 external redirect, ie. a new request!)
4. Internal rewrite in .htaccess (again - new request):
   `/index.php?dir=projects/&dir=projects/` (note that the request is still `/projects/?dir=projects/`)
   The doubling of the `dir=projects/` query param is a result of the `QSA` flag on the `RewriteRule` (which I assume is required for other requests?). Your PHP script simply sees a single `dir` GET param (the later overwrites the former), unless you included `dir[]=$1/` in your `RewriteRule` and you will end up with a 2-element array!

Your `RewriteRule` pattern also looks unnecessarily complex. You could simply make the trailing slash optional. ie:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?dir=$1/ [L,QSA]
```

---

Alternatively, having said all the above, you should probably leave `DirectorySlash On` (default) and simply make the trailing slash mandatory! For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?dir=$1/ [L,QSA]
```

mod_dir will now kick in *before* your internal rewrite (since it won't match without a trailing slash). This is also better for canonicalising your URLs and there are also potential security risks with turning it off.

Reference:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash

Comment: thank you w3d. I'll do some tests with your suggestion. I don't know about the negative vote, it's not me for sure. Thanks!

Comment: It works, I did some tests. Everything is fine. I am using the version with the DirectorySlash On and mandatory slash RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?dir=$1/ [L,QSA]