# HTACCESS Treat important directory as a parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

I want directory www.example.com/core to be translated into string, instead of just dissalowing access to it. is that possible?

UPDATE (STILL NO LUCK):

My current .htaccess

```
#Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

#Remove the comments below to enable enforcing HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteBase /public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ launcher.php?urls=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule . launcher.php [L]
```

Here are some scenarios:

I write a url `www.example.com/some-dir-that-does-not-exist` and it works fine.

I write a url `www.example.com/url-that-DOES-exist` and the browser redirects it to `www.example.com/url-that-DOES-exist/?url=url-that-DOES-exist`

Comment: Can you be more explicit? I mean what would the server response if i GET | POST | HEAD | WHATEVER request `http://www.example.com/core`?

Comment: i am not talking about directories that do not exist. those i have no problem with. but if i want a directory that DOES exist to be treated as one that does not. right now if i write www.example.com/core, the browser goes to www.example.com/core/?url=core

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want to achieve. If you add this rule `RewriteRule ^/core(/.*)?$ - [R=404,L]` does it do what you want? I don't really understand the part of ***to be translated into string***

Comment: it still redirects to `/core/?url=core` and now adds a 500 error

Comment: You want and existing directory to be treaten as a non-existing one?

Comment: yes exactly thats what i want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99891/discussion-between-eduardo-escobar-and-mikolaj-marciniak).

Comment: This problem is caused by mod_dir, as anubhava mentions in his answer. You can see this answer to another question for an explanation of what is actually happening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695015/htaccess-folder-as-parameter-to-root-index-php/31701005#31701005

Comment: how do i treat all files except the ones in /public/ directory to be treated as parameters? if a file does not exist, it is treated that way but not if it does exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is due to `mod_dir` module adding a trailing slash in front of real directories and making a 301 redirect after your rewrite rule.

To fix have it like this:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /launcher\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

#Remove the comments below to enable enforcing HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]    

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ launcher.php?urls=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: let me check this out

Comment: sorry, it does not work. still adds a trailing slash. maybe you want to move this discussion to chat ? i feel its going to be a long one

Comment: Nope it won't be long one as I suspect you are hitting your browser cache. Clear your browser cache and retest.

Comment: And btw I've already tested all of this code on my Apache. `localhost/core` becomes `localhost/core/` and it is still routed to `launcher.php?urls=core`

Comment: for me example.com/core becomes example.com/core/?url=core and example.com/core/ works fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99896/discussion-between-anubhava-and-mikolaj-marciniak).

Comment: this does work, i thought that going chrome incognito would assume cleared cache but when i explicitly cleared it, it did work. thank you very much! much appreciated!

Comment: i have come up with another security feature. i want to forbid access to ALL files except the ones in the public directory (excluding launcher.php)

Comment: or rather, instead of forbidding access, which would imply that this file DOES exist, i want all files except the ones in public directory to be treated like parameters (non-existing files already are treated that way)

Comment: @MikołajMarciniak: Requirement in your last comment is pretty big change from the rules at present. Please open a new question and we'll address it.

Comment: i have done so at this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630188/dissallowing-access-to-all-files-except-a-few-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Your code will become:

```
#Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

#Remove the comments below to enable enforcing HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /public

# Treat existing /core directory as non-existing (handled by launcher.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/core(/.*)?$
RewriteRule . launcher.php [L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ launcher.php?urls=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule . launcher.php [L]
```

Comment: still adds /core/url=core

Comment: Make sure to clear your browser's browsing data after modifying redirection rules in your .htaccess file.

Comment: what do u mean and why?

Comment: Your browser may be still following old redirections in your website.

Comment: i opened an incognito and its all the same