# Treating all files as parameters with few exceptions

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

UPDATE: Changed the title of this question to reflect what i want

I wish to treat all files in all directories as parameters, except all files inside the /public/ directory and all its subdirectories, using .htaccess.

I have tried many things, but none work. My current .htaccess file looks like this:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove access to .htaccess
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\.htaccess [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# remove access to launcher.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /launcher\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# enforce HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# treat existing directories as parameters
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]    

# handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ launcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This file does following things already:

- Treats all directories, existing or not, as parameters
- Dissallows access to .htaccess and launcher.php
- Enforces HTTPS
- Redirects all requests to launcher.php

Please do note that I wish to TREAT all files as parameters, NOT only dissallow access. Exceptions to this are ALL files inside of the /public/ folder and ALL its subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this .htaccess:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

# remove access to launcher.php and .htaccess
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\.htaccess [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# enforce HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# treat existing directories as parameters
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]    

# handle Front Controller for public/
RewriteRule ^(public)/?$ launcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(public/.*?)/?$ launcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

# handle remaining URLs as parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)url= [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*?)/?$ launcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Please rewrite your answer, because now im using launcher.php inside of root directory as you can see in my code.

Comment: The .htaccess that you see in my question resides in root, and its the only .htaccess file i have

Comment: Perfect, although I would ALSO like to treat launcher.php AND .htaccess to be treated as parameter

Comment: actually, the the files in public directory are not accessible, they are treated as parameters

Comment: that did it. i am checking the query string and everything outputs perfectly, although when I type www.example.com/public, the query string becomes public/ . for everything else it just becomes what i type, fx example.com/somedir becomes somedir in query string. not important to solve this, but if its possible i would like an answer to that as well :)

Comment: okay a new problem arose. On my live site, it works no problem. when im testing on localhost and i type `localhost/site` it shows a list of directories. if i type `localhost/site/` it works fine.

Comment: sorry, nothing changed. if i put all the files into root directory, ie localhost, it works fine. but if i put them inside of `site` directory, ie localhost/site, it lists all directories. localhost/site/ (with a backslash at the end), it works fine.

Comment: This answer is for .htaccess and launcher.php are in site soot so it must be placed there only.

Comment: i see. is there no quick regex magic that will make it more flexible so i can put it in any directory? :)